# Casting by C'tor does not work

Tags: c++

I have a little problem with this code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;    

class Array
{
    public:
        int* Arr;
        int size;

        Array();
    Array( const Array& A )
    {
        size = A.size;
        Arr = new int[size];

        for ( int i=0; i < size; i++ )
        {
            Arr[i] = A.Arr[i];
        }
    }

    Array(int size) { Arr = new int[size]; }

    Array( int* A ): size(5)  // takes only 5 arguments from A
    {
        Arr = new int[size];

        for ( int i=0; i < size; i++ )
        {
            Arr[i] = A[i];
        }
    }
};


Array& operator+ ( const Array& A , int* B )
{ 
    Array *Res = new Array(A);
    Res->size = A.size*2;

    for ( int i=A.size; i < Res->size; i++ )
        {
            Res->Arr[i] = B[i - A.size ];
        }

    return *Res;
}


void main()
{
    int A[] = {0,1,2,3,4} , *B;

    B = new int[5];

    for( int i=0; i<5; i++ )
    {
        B[i] = i+5;
    }

    Array Res = Array(A) + B;         // Using temporary object works
    Array Res = ( (Array)A ) + B;     // Forced cast also works good 
    Array Res1 = A + B;               // Automatic casting won't work, why?
}
```

the last line does not work, even though I implemented the `Array( int* A )` casting C'tor

it says:

```
error C2110: '+' : cannot add two pointers
```

what can be the problem?

Comment: The compiler has no idea that when working on `int[]` and `int*` that it should use your Array class.

Comment: Don't use `void main`, always use `int main`

Answer (score 2):

If you go by operator precedence and order of execution, you will understand why. For this simple statement:

```
r=a+b;
```

The expression `a+b` will be executed first, and then the result of this expression will be used for `=` operator. It is not the other way around. It is **not** evaluated this way:

```
(r=a)+b;
```

But as:

```
r=(a+b);
```

Hence, result type of `a+b` will be applied to `r=` expression. In your case, you are expecting `r=` to execute first, but that's wrong! In your case `a` and `b` both are pointers, and C/C++ doesn't allow two pointers to be added.

Comment: I was writing the same thing when you posted!

Comment: This really misses the point of the question. `Array Res1 = operator+(A, B);` would work. `Array Res1 = A + B;` doesn't work. You're saying that that's because the OP expects it to be treated as `(Array Res1 = A) + B;` (not even valid)? I highly doubt that.

Comment: No no no! `operator+(A,B)` wouldn't work either! Both are native types, you cannot overload operator+ where both binary-arguments are native.

Comment: @Ajay Just try it, it does work. (I tried it before commenting.)

Comment: @hvd, Yeah it works! But OP didn't mention that in his code. He just mentions forceful typecasting and automatic typecasting.

Comment: @Ajay I know the OP didn't mention that, but even by what the OP did mention, I don't see how you concluded that the OP thought `a = b + c;` would add anything other than `b` and `c`, let alone `T a = b + c;` where there isn't even an assignment. (Again, to be clear, if you do continue from that conclusion, your answer is of course entirely correct.)

Comment: Thank's to you all guys for the prompt answers
Ajay, what I'm trying to do is to see how casting by C'tor works.
So I assumed that operator+ expect to get Array+int* and instead get int* + int* will do an automatic casting from int* to Array ( and for this I built the C'tor "Array( int* A )", to make a temporary Array).

Answer (score 0):

You're expecting the compiler to know that it should use:

`Array& operator+ ( const Array& A , int* B )`.

But the first operand (`A`) is not a variable of type `Array`.

Hence the compiler cannot resolve the '+' operation.

Comment: the operator+ expects to get Array + int[] but instead it gets int[] + int[].

since the C'tor Array( int* A ) is not explicit, It's expected that it will make a temporary Array object, using the Array( int* A ) C'tor.

How can I make it work instead? the point is to concatenate two int[] type variables

Comment: You expect the compiler to look at every class in the whole program, in the hopes that maybe somewhere there's a class that a) can be constructed from `int*` and b) provides `operator+`. The compiler is not going to exert such heroic effort. The expression `A + B` doesn't mention class `Array` in any shape or form; nothing suggests to the compiler that `Array` should be considered at all, and so the compiler doesn't consider it.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Actually, since the `operator+` is not a member function, the rules are a bit different. If `Array` were constructible from a custom `struct S`, then `S() + B` would work. It's only because pointers are built-in types (more precisely, because built-in types don't have an associated namespace) that it doesn't.

Comment: OK I understand
so you are telling me that there is no other way to add to int* types?

Comment: Please note that `operator+` is normally expected to be associative. In other words, if you can do `A+B` then you should be able to do `B+A`, and the result should be identical. For this reason, `operator+` is usually defined as a global (friend) function rather than as a member function. In you case, you should probably implement two `operator+`, since the two operands (arguments) are of different types. At present, you will get a compilation error for `B+A`.

Comment: Yes I know this.
That code was built only for learning the casting by C'tor issue

Comment: No, there is no way to add int* types. More generally, there's no way to change how operators work on built-in types.